# Stop Trigger function to run multiple times in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

for some reason my trigger function (even when is called once) runs the trigger multiple times.

### Here is the code:-

```
$('.video-section ul li a').on({ 'touchstart' : function(){ 

    console.log("Touched"); 
    $(".video-section ul li a").trigger("click");

} });

$(".video-section ul li a").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("clicked");
  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

What happens is that the "click" function is run multiple times when it's triggered once by the "touch" function.

Any way, I can force it to run once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` gets fired 300ms after you touch the element whether you trigger it or not on the `touchstart`. So, because you trigger it on touchstart, it fires twice. You could do something like:

Example here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p2272vf/)

```
$('.video-section ul li a').on('click touchstart', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.type == "touchstart") {
       console.log("touchstart event");
       // whatever else on touch event
    } else if(e.type == "click") {
       console.log("click event");
       // whatever else on click event
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `$(this).click();` instead of `$('.video-section ul li a').trigger('click');` because the former will only trigger a click on the element that the `touchstart` event fired on. The later will trigger a click for every element that matches the selector.